# login script using session in php is not working can any tell me why

Tags: php

i Know I am making some small mistakes but I am not able to find where.  Can anyone please point it out? I want my page to be redirected to the index page when input values match with those of mysql table. But it is not working yet. Can you please check and let me know.

```
                    if(isset($_SESSION["manager"]))
                    {
                        header("location:index.php");
                        exit();
                    }
                    ?>

                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <title>Login for Photovale</title>

                    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <link href="css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

                    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
                    <![endif]-->

                    </head>

                    <body>


                    <?php
                    error_reporting(0);
                    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
                    $connect=  mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die('not connected');
                    $db=  mysql_select_db("photovale")or die('not connected');


                    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
                    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);



                    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) )
                    {

                        echo $sql=mysql_query("SELECT id from login WHERE user==$username && pass==$password");

                        echo $rows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
                        if($rows>0)
                        {
                            echo "rowsgenerated";
                            while($fetch=  mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                            {
                            $id=$fetch[id];

                            }
                            $_SESSION["id"]=$id;
                            $_SESSION["manager"]=$username;
                            $_SESSION["password"]=$password;
                            header("location:index.php");
                        }

                        //print_r($_REQUEST);

                    }

                    ?>

                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                                            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">Log in</div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <form method="post" role="form">
                                                                    <fieldset>
                                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" type="text" autofocus="" required>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="" required>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <!---div class="checkbox">
                                                                                    <label>
                                                                                            <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                                                                    </label>
                                                                            </div--->
                                                                    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                                    </fieldset>
                                                            </form>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.col-->
                            </div><!-- /.row -->    



                    </body>

                    </html>
```

Comment: Note: `mysql_*` functions are removed from PHP.

Comment: can you tell me currently what happen with your this code ?

Comment: this code is not redirecting to the index.php when submitting the username and password

Comment: Does `"rowsgenerated";` get echoed ?

Comment: no it is not going there

Comment: I think error is in sql query...Can anyone point it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write login query like this and it will redirect

```
//login script
  if(isset($_POST['login'])){
                    $username = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
                    $password = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));

                    //if username or password is empty
                    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Fill in all the fields</div>";
                        exit();
                    }

                    //check username and password match the db record
                    $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM 'user' WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($q) != 1){
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid username or password</div>";
                        exit(); 
                    }
    //fetch the if of the loggedin user start the session
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
                    //set the session with loggedin user id
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    exit();
                }
            ?>


   LOGIN p[![enter image description here][1]][1]age

 and the page will redirect to index.php

      [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Guys answer was simple...actually error was there in the sql query it is working now.
echo $sql1="SELECT `id` FROM `login` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
                                echo $sql=  mysql_query($sql1);

Comment: @sonu kumar said exactly the same thing at his answer. you should accept his answer